# apache FileUpload, tmp files deleted prematurely

Tags: java, apache, servlets, file-upload

From my server logs, when I attempt to call getInputStream on a FileItem:

```
6/22/12 14:31:14 ERROR c.s.u.WizardUploadReceiver:225          | Jumploader: Problem uploading zip13afcchr.psd - Failed to handle post properly
java.io.FileNotFoundException: uploadtemp\upload__3e026c78_13815404c62__7ff2_00000141.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:236) ~[commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
...
```

I've verified, as far as I can tell, that the associated File and FileItem, and DiskFileItemFactory are not out of scope (eligible for garbage collection) until after my servlet method returns.

I simply looking for other potential situations that might cause FileUpload to delete these temp files prematurely.

Additional info: I'm only seeing this problem when specific clients upload files.  The same files sent to the same servlet on other clients don't seem to result in this issue.  I haven't yet found a difference between clients that are having problems and clients that are not.

Comment: Does you have "uploadtemp" dir in your root dir?

Comment: Note you have TWO errors.  `Problem uploading...` followed by `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: ilya - yes, in a subdir under the app's root dir

Comment: Jim Garrison - you are mis-reading the log message.  I am logging a custom message along with the associated exception stack trace.  You may want to read up on logging frameworks.

Comment: Are you using Jumploader to upload files ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jumploader.  Why do you ask?

Answer (score -1):

May be size of your file more then 10 Kb (default threshold). When you parse request with DiskFileItemFactory you should set a new threshold something like:

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

**factory.setSizeThreshold(102400);**

List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

Comment: No, that's not it at all